# How can I use a variable in an AppleScript?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I have a program written in swift and I was wondering how I could reference a variable (String) in my terminal command.

This is what I have tried but I am not having any success.

```
    var clientUsed : String = "Safari"
    var killApp: NSAppleScript?
    let killCommand = "do shell script \"killall " + clientUsed\"
    killApp = NSAppleScript(source:killCommand)
```

How do I structure this correctly?

The command should say the following:

```
killall Safari
```

Where safari is a variable chosen by the user.

I assume anyone with swift or obj-c knowledge will be able to help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is via string interpolation.  Inside your string literal, enclose a variable in `\()` to have it’s string representation inserted at that point:

```
let killCommand = "do shell script \"killall \(clientUsed)\""
```

Your original idea of using `+` would also work (less neat though), but you needed to add an additional string literal on the end:

```
let killCommand = "do shell script \"killall " + clientUsed + "\""
```

Comment: I tried this same method for my one other command but it didn't work. Did I type it correctly?

"do shell script \"open --hide --background /Applications/ \(clientUsed).app\""

Comment: it’s missing the `\ ` in front of the open paren (i.e. `"do shell script \"open --hide --background /Applications/ \(clientUsed).app\""`)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working :( It should read: `open --hide --background /Applications/Safari.app`

Comment: I figured it out, don't worry! :) There was an extra space after /Applications/ that ruined the path.